# How to control specific location of Conky

Tags: conky

I've got Conky installed via Conky Manager and I'm running the Gotham theme. It looks great and I is really useful, but I've run into an issue. It covers part of my background, making part of the Conky widget hard to read. I've read [this Ubuntu Forums post on it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=922881), but I still can't get it to be aligned where I want it, about 50 pixels to the right.

[image: conky]

Obviously that's slightly annoying.

I've messed with the gap_x property, but I cannot get it to work right. One would think that since positive numbers move it away from the current align position (in my case right,) negative numbers would move it closer in that direction. However, this isn't true apparently, as negative numbers seem to just be ignored.

What can I do change the position?

Comment: Changing the gap_x, gap_y values would move it from 0,0 which is usually the upper left corner of the screen (though it looks like you can change that with the alignment property). This is why you always need positive numbers. My guess is you're using small numbers (thinking you only need to move a little in reference to the current position) when you need a big number in reference to the corner.

Comment: This page will prove really helpful to anyone with conky issues: http://conky.sourceforge.net/docs.html

Comment: @chaskes Ah. I've got the 0,0 set to the upper-right-hand corner and when I change those values at all, it just moves them left, instead of right. So, I figured I'd try setting it to upper-left-hand corner and then putting in big numbers to make it jump across to the right. However, I don't think it can handle numbers above ~1500. Above that it just jumps back to where it was originally.

Comment: maybe there is extra spacing as part of the theme?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this by editing the gotham config file in /home/USER/.conky/Gotham

edit

```
gap_x 300
gap_x 350
```

experiment a bit with it, if you want to change high you can also change

```
gap_y 50
```

Hope this helps